# Basic C++ Recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

I am trying to count series of: 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5 + ...
But I had problem with my output:

> Insert how many series's number will be counted : 3 // I am input 3
>   Total = 1 // This is the problem, the output should shown  = 1.8333

My program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int recursion ( int n );
int main ()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Insert how many number will be counted : ";cin >> n;
    cout << "Total  = " << recursion(n);
}
int recursion (int a)
{
    int result;
    if ( a >= 1 )
    {
        result = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        result = ( pow ( a , -1 )  + recursion ( pow ( ( a - 1 ) , -1 ) ) );
    }
    return (result);
}
```

Comment: your code has `int`s only, how do you expect this to print a floating point number? Use `double` or `float` instead

Comment: One way to tell that your problem has nothing to do with recursion is to look at it, and then check to see that your problem has nothing to do with recursion.  *(Alternately, extract a simple example which doesn't involve recursion at all and see that your calculation results are still integers.)*

Comment: The reason is 1/2,1/3 ... all are 0 in integer math.

Comment: And also, there is no recursion, according to end condition of recursion: if value of a is greater or equal to 1 (which is always the case!) just return 1, else do recursion

Comment: Don't use `pow(x, -1)`, as it is a waste.  Use division, less overhead, i.e. 1.0/2.0, 1.0/3.0.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, use *floating point* types, such as `double` or `float`.

In integer division, 1/3 == 0.

Here's an iterative example:

```
const unsigned int NUMBER_OF_TERMS = 100;
double result = 0.0;
double denominator = 2.0;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_TERMS; ++i)
{
  result = result + 1.0 / denominator;
  denominator = denomenator + 1.0;
}
```

Your code should use floating point constants (with decimal points) and floating point variables (of type `double` or `float`).

**Edit 1: Basic recursion**
In some cases of recursion, thinking of the solution backwards may help the implementation.

For example, the series starts with 1.0/2.0.  However, since the sum operation doesn't depend on order, we can start with 1.0/5.0 and work backwards:

```
result = 1.0/5.0 + 1.0/4.0 + 1.0/3.0 + 1.0/2.0
```

This allows the denominator to be used as the condition for ending the recursion.

```
double recursive_sum(double denominator)
{
  if (denominator < 2)
  {
    return 0.0;
  }
  return recursive_sum(denominator - 1.0)
         + 1.0 / denominator;
}
```

Comment: why `return 0.0` if denominator < 2 ?

Comment: I'm returning 0.0 because it's the first starting value.  From your question, the series starts with 1.0/2.0 and not 1.0.  Also note that the function is called (recursively) with `denominator - 1.0`, which means that eventually, the denominator will be less than 2.0.

Comment: why not return 0.5 ? when denominator < 2 so the value is 1.0/2.0,  and the result of 1.0/2.0 is 0.5 not 0.0 right ?